# How to handle error handling at single place in rxjava using wrapper

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Hi I made a `CallbackWrapper` to handle error handling at single place in `rxjava`.

```
abstract class CallbackWrapper<T : BaseResponse> : DisposableObserver<T>() {

    protected abstract fun onSuccess(t: T)

    override fun onNext(t: T) {
        onSuccess(t)
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        when (e) {
            is HttpException -> {
                val responseBody = (e as HttpException).response().errorBody()
                responseBody?.let {
                    // todo
                }
            }
            is SocketTimeoutException -> {
                // todo
            }
            is IOException -> {
                // todo
            }
            else -> {
                e.message?.let {
                    // todo
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onComplete() {

    }

    private fun getErrorMessage(responseBody: ResponseBody): String {
        val jsonObject = JSONObject(responseBody.string())
        return jsonObject.getString(("message"))
    }
}
```

I am calling it like below in my `LoginViewModel` class.

```
apiHelper.doServerLoginApiCall(email, password)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(object : CallbackWrapper<LoginResponse>() {

                        override fun onSuccess(loginResponse: LoginResponse) {
                            progressVisibility.set(View.GONE)
                        }
                    })
```

I have `onError` method in `CallbackWrapper` which notifies if there is any error. I don't know how to send this error information to view model. I am using MVVM design pattern.

Can anyone hint me ?

Comment: why can't you do the same thing as in the abstract `onSuccess` method?

Comment: do you mean pass error in second parameter of on success ?

Comment: no, I mean defining another abstract method, something like: `onFail`.